# Solve the differential equation using Variation of Parameter.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the following differential to solve by using variation of parameter.

$y'' +3y'+2 =\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$

**My Attempt:**  I first find the C.F. The C.F is $c_1 e^{-2x} + c_2e^{-x}$. Let's suppose $u(x) = e^{-2x}$  and $v(x) = e^{-x}$.

So the complete solution will be $y =A(x) e^{-2x} + B(x)e^{-x}$ .  Here $A(x) = -\int\frac{v(x)}{uv' - u'v}$  and $B(x) = \int \frac{u(x)}{uv' - u'v}$.

Now I am getting $A(x) = - \int \frac{e^x}{x}$  and $B(x) = \ln(x)+c_4$.

Now how to determine $A(x) = - \int \frac{e^x}{x}$. As far as I know , $\int \frac{e^x}{x}$ is an infinite series. What to do now? Should I keep $- \int \frac{e^x}{x}$ this in the solution without solving?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I can not understand properly. What to do ? Should I keep that integral as it is  in the solution ?@Moo

Comment: I was trying to do it by multiplying both sides by $e^x$.  But that integral again came and  I again got stuck in that integral.@Moo